# GCC ld: can't find -lcurses

Tags: gcc

```
Make install
```

Produces this output:

```
    /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libcurses.so when searching for -lcurses
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurses
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:125: recipe for target 'samtools' failed
make: *** [samtools] Error 1
```

I can't figure out why this won't work. I know how make tool work, but I'm newbie in linuxOS.

```
    # Makefile for samtools, utilities for the Sequence Alignment/Map format.
#
#    Copyright (C) 2008-2014 Genome Research Ltd.
#    Portions copyright (C) 2010-2012 Broad Institute.
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
# in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
# to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
# copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
# furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
#
# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
# all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL
# THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
# FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
# DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

CC       = gcc
CPPFLAGS = $(DFLAGS) $(INCLUDES)
CFLAGS   = -g -Wall -O2
LDFLAGS  =
LDLIBS   =
DFLAGS=     -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_CURSES_LIB=1
LOBJS=      bam_aux.o bam.o bam_import.o sam.o \
            sam_header.o bam_plbuf.o
AOBJS=      bam_index.o bam_plcmd.o sam_view.o \
            bam_cat.o bam_md.o bam_reheader.o bam_sort.o bedidx.o kprobaln.o \
            bam_rmdup.o bam_rmdupse.o bam_mate.o bam_stat.o bam_color.o \
            bamtk.o bam2bcf.o bam2bcf_indel.o errmod.o sample.o \
            cut_target.o phase.o bam2depth.o padding.o bedcov.o bamshuf.o \
            faidx.o stats.o stats_isize.o bam_flags.o bam_split.o \
            bam_tview.o bam_tview_curses.o bam_tview_html.o bam_lpileup.o
INCLUDES=   -I. -I$(HTSDIR)
LIBCURSES=  -lcurses # -lXCurses

prefix      = /usr/local
exec_prefix = $(prefix)
bindir      = $(exec_prefix)/bin
mandir      = $(prefix)/share/man
man1dir     = $(mandir)/man1

MKDIR_P = mkdir -p
INSTALL = install -p
INSTALL_PROGRAM = $(INSTALL)
INSTALL_DATA    = $(INSTALL) -m 644
INSTALL_DIR     = $(MKDIR_P) -m 755


PROGRAMS = samtools

BUILT_MISC_PROGRAMS = \
    misc/ace2sam misc/maq2sam-long misc/maq2sam-short \
    misc/md5fa misc/md5sum-lite misc/wgsim

MISC_PROGRAMS = \
    $(BUILT_MISC_PROGRAMS) \
    misc/blast2sam.pl misc/bowtie2sam.pl misc/export2sam.pl \
    misc/interpolate_sam.pl misc/novo2sam.pl \
    misc/plot-bamstats misc/psl2sam.pl \
    misc/sam2vcf.pl misc/samtools.pl misc/seq_cache_populate.pl \
    misc/soap2sam.pl \
    misc/varfilter.py misc/wgsim_eval.pl misc/zoom2sam.pl

BUILT_TEST_PROGRAMS = \
    test/merge/test_bam_translate \
    test/merge/test_pretty_header \
    test/merge/test_rtrans_build \
    test/merge/test_trans_tbl_init \
    test/split/test_count_rg \
    test/split/test_expand_format_string \
    test/split/test_filter_header_rg \
    test/split/test_parse_args \
    test/vcf-miniview

all: $(PROGRAMS) $(BUILT_MISC_PROGRAMS) $(BUILT_TEST_PROGRAMS)


# Adjust $(HTSDIR) to point to your top-level htslib directory
HTSDIR = htslib-1.2.1
include $(HTSDIR)/htslib.mk
HTSLIB = $(HTSDIR)/libhts.a
BGZIP  = $(HTSDIR)/bgzip


PACKAGE_VERSION = 1.2

# If building from a Git repository, replace $(PACKAGE_VERSION) with the Git
# description of the working tree: either a release tag with the same value
# as $(PACKAGE_VERSION) above, or an exact description likely based on a tag.
# $(shell), :=, etc are GNU Make-specific.  If you don't have GNU Make,
# comment out this conditional.
ifneq "$(wildcard .git)" ""
PACKAGE_VERSION := $(shell git describe --always --dirty)

# Force version.h to be remade if $(PACKAGE_VERSION) has changed.
version.h: $(if $(wildcard version.h),$(if $(findstring "$(PACKAGE_VERSION)",$(shell cat version.h)),,force))
endif

# If you don't have GNU Make but are building from a Git repository, you may
# wish to replace this with a rule that always rebuilds version.h:
# version.h: force
#   echo '#define SAMTOOLS_VERSION "`git describe --always --dirty`"' > $@
version.h:
    echo '#define SAMTOOLS_VERSION "$(PACKAGE_VERSION)"' > $@


.SUFFIXES: .c .o

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<


lib:libbam.a

libbam.a:$(LOBJS)
    $(AR) -csru $@ $(LOBJS)

samtools: $(AOBJS) libbam.a $(HTSLIB)
    $(CC) -pthread $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(AOBJS) libbam.a $(HTSLIB) $(LDLIBS) $(LIBCURSES) -lm -lz

bam_h = bam.h $(htslib_bgzf_h) $(htslib_sam_h)
bam2bcf_h = bam2bcf.h $(htslib_vcf_h) errmod.h
bam_lpileup_h = bam_lpileup.h $(htslib_sam_h)
bam_plbuf_h = bam_plbuf.h $(htslib_sam_h)
bam_tview_h = bam_tview.h $(htslib_hts_h) $(htslib_sam_h) $(htslib_faidx_h) $(bam2bcf_h) $(HTSDIR)/htslib/khash.h $(bam_lpileup_h)
sam_h = sam.h $(htslib_sam_h) $(bam_h)
sample_h = sample.h $(HTSDIR)/htslib/kstring.h

bam.o: bam.c $(bam_h) sam_header.h
bam2bcf.o: bam2bcf.c $(htslib_sam_h) $(HTSDIR)/htslib/kstring.h $(HTSDIR)/htslib/kfunc.h $(bam2bcf_h) errmod.h
bam2bcf_indel.o: bam2bcf_indel.c $(htslib_sam_h) $(bam2bcf_h) kprobaln.h $(HTSDIR)/htslib/khash.h $(HTSDIR)/htslib/ksort.h
bam2depth.o: bam2depth.c $(htslib_sam_h) samtools.h
bam_aux.o: bam_aux.c
bam_cat.o: bam_cat.c $(htslib_bgzf_h) $(bam_h)
bam_color.o: bam_color.c $(bam_h)
bam_import.o: bam_import.c $(HTSDIR)/htslib/kstring.h $(bam_h) $(HTSDIR)/htslib/kseq.h
bam_index.o: bam_index.c $(htslib_hts_h) $(htslib_sam_h) $(HTSDIR)/htslib/khash.h
bam_lpileup.o: bam_lpileup.c $(bam_plbuf_h) $(bam_lpileup_h) $(HTSDIR)/htslib/ksort.h
bam_mate.o: bam_mate.c $(bam_h)
bam_md.o: bam_md.c $(htslib_faidx_h) $(sam_h) kprobaln.h
bam_pileup.o: bam_pileup.c $(sam_h)
bam_plbuf.o: bam_plbuf.c $(htslib_hts_h) $(htslib_sam_h) $(bam_plbuf_h)
bam_plcmd.o: bam_plcmd.c $(htslib_sam_h) $(htslib_faidx_h) $(HTSDIR)/htslib/kstring.h $(HTSDIR)/htslib/khash_str2int.h sam_header.h samtools.h $(bam2bcf_h) $(sample_h)
bam_reheader.o: bam_reheader.c $(htslib_bgzf_h) $(bam_h)
bam_rmdup.o: bam_rmdup.c $(sam_h) $(HTSDIR)/htslib/khash.h
bam_rmdupse.o: bam_rmdupse.c $(sam_h) $(HTSDIR)/htslib/khash.h $(HTSDIR)/htslib/klist.h
bam_sort.o: bam_sort.c $(HTSDIR)/htslib/ksort.h $(HTSDIR)/htslib/khash.h $(HTSDIR)/htslib/klist.h $(HTSDIR)/htslib/kstring.h $(htslib_sam_h)
bam_stat.o: bam_stat.c $(bam_h) samtools.h
bam_tview.o: bam_tview.c $(bam_tview_h) $(htslib_faidx_h) $(htslib_sam_h) $(htslib_bgzf_h)
bam_tview_curses.o: bam_tview_curses.c $(bam_tview_h)
bam_tview_html.o: bam_tview_html.c $(bam_tview_h)
bam_flags.o: bam_flags.c $(sam_h)
bamshuf.o: bamshuf.c $(htslib_sam_h) $(HTSDIR)/htslib/ksort.h samtools.h
bamtk.o: bamtk.c $(htslib_hts_h) version.h samtools.h
bedcov.o: bedcov.c $(HTSDIR)/htslib/kstring.h $(htslib_sam_h) $(HTSDIR)/htslib/kseq.h
bedidx.o: bedidx.c $(HTSDIR)/htslib/ksort.h $(HTSDIR)/htslib/kseq.h $(HTSDIR)/htslib/khash.h
cut_target.o: cut_target.c $(bam_h) errmod.h $(htslib_faidx_h)
errmod.o: errmod.c errmod.h $(HTSDIR)/htslib/ksort.h
kprobaln.o: kprobaln.c kprobaln.h
padding.o: padding.c sam_header.h $(sam_h) $(bam_h) $(htslib_faidx_h)
phase.o: phase.c $(htslib_sam_h) errmod.h $(HTSDIR)/htslib/kseq.h $(HTSDIR)/htslib/khash.h $(HTSDIR)/htslib/ksort.h
sam.o: sam.c $(htslib_faidx_h) $(sam_h)
sam_header.o: sam_header.c sam_header.h $(HTSDIR)/htslib/khash.h
sam_view.o: sam_view.c $(htslib_sam_h) $(htslib_faidx_h) $(HTSDIR)/htslib/kstring.h $(HTSDIR)/htslib/khash.h samtools.h
sample.o: sample.c $(sample_h) $(HTSDIR)/htslib/khash.h
stats_isize.o: stats_isize.c stats_isize.h $(HTSDIR)/htslib/khash.h
stats.o: stats.c $(sam_h) sam_header.h samtools.h stats_isize.h $(HTSDIR)/htslib/khash.h $(HTSDIR)/htslib/khash_str2int.h $(htslib_faidx_h)


# test programs

# For tests that might use it, set $REF_PATH explicitly to use only reference
# areas within the test suite (or set it to ':' to use no reference areas).
# (regression.sh sets $REF_PATH to a subdirectory itself.)
check test: samtools $(BGZIP) $(BUILT_TEST_PROGRAMS)
    REF_PATH=: test/test.pl --exec bgzip=$(BGZIP)
    test/merge/test_bam_translate test/merge/test_bam_translate.tmp
    test/merge/test_pretty_header
    test/merge/test_rtrans_build
    test/merge/test_trans_tbl_init
    cd test/mpileup && ./regression.sh
    test/split/test_count_rg
    test/split/test_expand_format_string
    test/split/test_filter_header_rg
    test/split/test_parse_args


test/merge/test_bam_translate: test/merge/test_bam_translate.o test/test.o $(HTSLIB)
    $(CC) -pthread $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ test/merge/test_bam_translate.o test/test.o $(HTSLIB) $(LDLIBS) -lz

test/merge/test_pretty_header: test/merge/test_pretty_header.o $(HTSLIB)
    $(CC) -pthread $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ test/merge/test_pretty_header.o $(HTSLIB) $(LDLIBS) -lz

test/merge/test_rtrans_build: test/merge/test_rtrans_build.o $(HTSLIB)
    $(CC) -pthread $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ test/merge/test_rtrans_build.o $(HTSLIB) $(LDLIBS) -lz

test/merge/test_trans_tbl_init: test/merge/test_trans_tbl_init.o $(HTSLIB)
    $(CC) -pthread $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ test/merge/test_trans_tbl_init.o $(HTSLIB) $(LDLIBS) -lz

test/split/test_count_rg: test/split/test_count_rg.o test/test.o $(HTSLIB)
    $(CC) -pthread $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ test/split/test_count_rg.o test/test.o $(HTSLIB) $(LDLIBS) -lz

test/split/test_expand_format_string: test/split/test_expand_format_string.o test/test.o $(HTSLIB)
    $(CC) -pthread $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ test/split/test_expand_format_string.o test/test.o $(HTSLIB) $(LDLIBS) -lz

test/split/test_filter_header_rg: test/split/test_filter_header_rg.o test/test.o $(HTSLIB)
    $(CC) -pthread $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ test/split/test_filter_header_rg.o test/test.o $(HTSLIB) $(LDLIBS) -lz

test/split/test_parse_args: test/split/test_parse_args.o test/test.o $(HTSLIB)
    $(CC) -pthread $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ test/split/test_parse_args.o test/test.o $(HTSLIB) $(LDLIBS) -lz

test/vcf-miniview: test/vcf-miniview.o $(HTSLIB)
    $(CC) -pthread $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ test/vcf-miniview.o $(HTSLIB) $(LDLIBS) -lz

test_test_h = test/test.h $(htslib_sam_h)

test/merge/test_bam_translate.o: test/merge/test_bam_translate.c $(test_test_h) bam_sort.o
test/merge/test_pretty_header.o: test/merge/test_pretty_header.c bam_sort.o
test/merge/test_rtrans_build.o: test/merge/test_rtrans_build.c bam_sort.o
test/merge/test_trans_tbl_init.o: test/merge/test_trans_tbl_init.c bam_sort.o
test/split/test_count_rg.o: test/split/test_count_rg.c bam_split.o $(test_test_h)
test/split/test_expand_format_string.o: test/split/test_expand_format_string.c bam_split.o $(test_test_h)
test/split/test_filter_header_rg.o: test/split/test_filter_header_rg.c bam_split.o $(test_test_h)
test/split/test_parse_args.o: test/split/test_parse_args.c bam_split.o $(test_test_h)
test/test.o: test/test.c $(htslib_sam_h) $(test_test_h)
test/vcf-miniview.o: test/vcf-miniview.c $(htslib_vcf_h)


# misc programs

misc/ace2sam: misc/ace2sam.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ misc/ace2sam.o $(LDLIBS) -lz

misc/maq2sam-short: misc/maq2sam-short.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ misc/maq2sam-short.o $(LDLIBS) -lz

misc/maq2sam-long: misc/maq2sam-long.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ misc/maq2sam-long.o $(LDLIBS) -lz

misc/md5fa: misc/md5fa.o misc/md5.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ misc/md5fa.o misc/md5.o $(LDLIBS) -lz

misc/md5sum-lite: misc/md5sum-lite.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ misc/md5sum-lite.o $(LDLIBS)

misc/wgsim: misc/wgsim.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ misc/wgsim.o $(LDLIBS) -lm -lz

misc/ace2sam.o: misc/ace2sam.c $(HTSDIR)/htslib/kstring.h $(HTSDIR)/htslib/kseq.h
misc/md5.o: misc/md5.c misc/md5.h
misc/md5fa.o: misc/md5fa.c misc/md5.h $(HTSDIR)/htslib/kseq.h
misc/wgsim.o: misc/wgsim.c $(HTSDIR)/htslib/kseq.h

misc/maq2sam-short.o: misc/maq2sam.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c -o $@ misc/maq2sam.c

misc/maq2sam-long.o: misc/maq2sam.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -DMAQ_LONGREADS -c -o $@ misc/maq2sam.c

misc/md5sum-lite.o: misc/md5.c misc/md5.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -DMD5SUM_MAIN -c -o $@ misc/md5.c


install: $(PROGRAMS) $(BUILT_MISC_PROGRAMS)
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(DESTDIR)$(bindir) $(DESTDIR)$(man1dir)
    $(INSTALL_PROGRAM) $(PROGRAMS) $(MISC_PROGRAMS) $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)
    $(INSTALL_DATA) samtools.1 $(DESTDIR)$(man1dir)


testclean:
    -rm -f test/*.new test/*.tmp test/*/*.new test/*/*.tmp
    -cd test/mpileup && rm -f FAIL-*.out* PASS-*.out* anomalous.[bc]*am indels.[bc]*am mpileup.*.[cs]*am mpileup.*.crai overlap50.[bc]*am expected/1.out

mostlyclean: testclean
    -rm -f *.o misc/*.o test/*.o test/*/*.o version.h

clean: mostlyclean
    -rm -f $(PROGRAMS) libbam.a $(BUILT_MISC_PROGRAMS) $(BUILT_TEST_PROGRAMS)

distclean: clean
    -rm -f TAGS

clean-all: clean clean-htslib


tags:
    ctags -f TAGS *.[ch] misc/*.[ch]


force:


.PHONY: all check clean clean-all distclean force install
.PHONY: lib mostlyclean tags test testclean
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a development library for ncurses installed, i.e., [`ncurses-devel`](https://software.opensuse.org/package/ncurses-devel) (for SuSE).

Without the *development* library, the shared libraries for ncurses are only present as *runtime* files.